# SEO pages in VUEJS? Other solutions then migrate to NUXTJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

We building a vuejs app. I read a lot of issues in case of SEO pages, and the best solution is to mirgate the app to nuxtjs and create SSR SEO pages?

Is this the best way or other solutions?

best remco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case of SEO, almost all single page application (SPA) have poor SEO. it's because these kind of website pages are not fully rendered by search engine indexing bots and things like meta tags and meta descriptions and page content are not available for these bots. so you have two solutions:

1- convert all your webpages to static HTML file. this way your pages are fully static and fully loaded so bots can detect everything. but as the name suggest, static pages may not be very useful since you know, they are static.

2- use SSR (server side rendering), for this you need to use something like NUXT. but the thing is, you need to deploy your nuxt application on a nodejs enviroment. so many shared hostings won't do the job. in general, SSO is a good solution if you really care about the SEO, but you need that node js server to render your code and return the result to clients (like bots and users)

Comment: or use a prerender service like prerender.io

Comment: There is a third option which is kind of midground between the two; you prerender pages with the static scaffolding that excludes the dynamic data. these prerendered html pages sit on the server and can be scraped by SEO bots. When the user loads the page, first static prerendered html is sent and then it is ```hydrated```, i.e. fed with the dynamic data. There are prerendering libraries for Vue. One downside is the static page skeleton is sometimes visible before being hydrated with data, causing flickers or possibly reduced UX (if dynamic data is too large).